# CSS getting equal spacing between divs with multiple spans

Tags: css, flexbox

I have sets of `div`s, each currently with two `span`s in them that have text. They are currently in a flexbox where they live quite happily.  The designer where I work wants the "blocks" of text to sit 24px apart from each other. The catch is that the 24px should start at the end of the longer span. Is this possible?

As you can see below, the spacing starts from the right of the longer text, and ends at the beginning of the text block next to it. Since the spans have different lengths, there would not be homogeneity where the next block over starts. I brought this up, but this is the instruction...

[image]

The code looks like this.

```
   <div class="wrapper">
          <div>
            <span>
              <Trans>Ref Code</Trans>
            </span>
            <span>{me.advisor.referralCode}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>
              <Trans>State/Province</Trans>
            </span>
            <span>
              <Trans>{postalCodeToProvince(me.advisor.postalCode)}</Trans>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>
              <Trans>Plan</Trans>
            </span>
            <span>
              <Trans>{products}</Trans>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>
              <Trans>Create on</Trans>
            </span>
            <span>{moment(me.advisor.stripeCreatedAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>
              <Trans>Next User Date</Trans>
            </span>
            <span>{me.advisor.nextAssignment.details.on ? me.advisor.nextAssignment.details.on : "Expired"}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>
              <Trans>Status</Trans>
            </span>
            <span>
              <Trans>{me.advisor.status}</Trans>
            </span>
          </div>
         </div>
```

[Here is a little codepen i made to outline how i am currently doing the css](https://codepen.io/samunt/pen/RwRORxy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply theses settings to the flex children (and delete the others), and delete `justify-content: space-evenly;` from the `.wrapper`:

```
.wrapper>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 24px;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 54px;
  margin-left: 64px;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 24px;
  margin-top: 12px; /* whatever setting desired */
}

.wrapper>div span:first-child {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3c4142;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper>div span:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #a5aeb0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <span>
                  <Trans>Ref Code</Trans>
                </span>
    <span>001209832u1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
                  <Trans>State/Province</Trans>
                </span>
    <span>
                  <Trans>ONTARIO</Trans>
                </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
                  <Trans>Plan</Trans>
                </span>
    <span>
                  <Trans>FunPlan</Trans>
                </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
                  <Trans>Create on</Trans>
                </span>
    <span>2020-09-14</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
                  <Trans>Next User Date</Trans>
                </span>
    <span>Expired</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
                  <Trans>Status</Trans>
                </span>
    <span>
                  <Trans>Dead</Trans>
                </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may make use of flexbox's `gap` property to set spacing between columns. Add `gap: 24px;` and remove `justify-content` and `flex` as shown below.

```css
.wrapper {
  gap: 24px;
  /* justify-content: space-evenly; */

  div {
    /* flex: 0 16%; */
  }
}
```

Comment: this did not work. although i am happy to learn about gap. i had never head of that before